# Cordova: How to change HTML source directory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ant

I am trying to use Cordova 3.4 in conjunction with AngularJS. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.portlandwebworks.com/blog/combining-yeoman-angularjs-and-cordova-mobile-development) and at some point it asks me to alter html.source.dir and html.asset.dir in ant.properties file. However, I am not being able to find this file anywhere in my source directory.
How do I change html source directory in Cordova?

Regards,

JadeSync.

Answer (score 2):

turns out ant.properties do not come bundled with new versions of Cordova. I had to alter Gruntfile.js to change these directories.