# How do I change www to another directory in Cordova?

Tags: cordova

I'm using Cordova 7 (so this [Cordova: How to change HTML source directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886257/cordova-how-to-change-html-source-directory) does not apply)

I am trying to find a way of changing Cordova from reading `www` and use something else such as `dist` but I can't find the setting in `config.xml` is there anywhere else I should look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not supported by Cordova, you have to use `www`, you will need a hook or build task that copies your `dist` folder content to the `www` folder.

On iOS, if you use Cordova as a component (not regular project, but a native project where you use Cordova as a dependency), then you can set the `wwwFolderName` of the `CDVViewController` you create.

Or in the Cordova project created in `platforms/ios` you can edit the `MainViewController.m` code to add `self.wwwFolderName = @"dist";` in the `init` method. But this is more like a hack as the native project might be restored to the original source after certain actions.

On Android it's not possible at all even when using as a component, the only way would be to change the source code, replacing all the occurrences of `file:///android_asset/www/` to `file:///android_asset/dist/`

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion is to **create a symbolic link** called "www" for your directory ("build" for example), on windows you can do it like this:

```
mklink /J www build
```

**note**: this creates a junction / hard link, ie changes to www will be reflected on build and vice versa)

Comment: interesting... to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

In the year 2022 on MacOS and Cordova 11.0.0 this is possible by setting a symbolic link in the terminal:

```
ln -s /my/desired/distdir /cordova-dir/www
```

Cordova will use /cordova-dir/www while the content of that is on /my/desired/distdir.

Hope that helps...